# laravel get relationship with multiple foriegn keys

Tags: php, laravel

I have three tables

Teams

```
id | Name
```

Winners

```
id | user_id | league_id
```

team_user

```
team_id | user_id | league_id
```

What I am trying to do in my `Winner.php` model is create a relationship that ties a winner to a team via the `user_id` and `league_id`

So basically I can call `Winner->team` and it will return the Team that the Winner belongs to where the `user_id` and `league_id` all match.

I was thinking

```
public function team()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Team', 'user_id', 'league_id');
 }
```

But that doesnt work obviously. I am scratching my head since I have all the info I need to get the team associate to that `league_id` and `user_id`.

Comment: your db schema looks confusing, and as you've used a pivot table do you intend that a winner can belong to many teams? and why do winners and team_user both have league_id field?. looks like duplication to me

Comment: @SapneshNaik I can show my whole DB schema and it would make more sense why it is set up like that but didnt think it pertain to the question at hand.

Comment: then the team_user should have a winner_id or is user_id refers to id of winner?

Comment: It seems that `team_user` is a ternary relationship. Laravel does not support those mainly because most of the time people use them wrongly. Not sure if this is one of those times because I don't know what goals your design is trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

if your winner model returns multiple team use below code:

```
public function teams()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Team', 'user_id', 'league_id');
}
```

if your winner model returns only one team use below code:

```
public function team()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Team', 'user_id', 'league_id');
}
```

Note:Here 3rd parameter in belogsTo() specifying your parent table's custom key

Answer (score 0):

You can attach additional `where()` clause:

```
public function team()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Team', 'user_id', 'user_id')->where('league_id', $this->league_id);
}
```

**Note:** This will work with `lazy loading` only. Look [here](https://laravel.io/forum/02-16-2016-laravel-52-eloquent-relationship-with-two-composite-keys), it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I just used this as a function and not a relationship and looped through in my controller. not the best but all I got to work:

Winner.php

```
public function team()
  {

    $team_id = DB::table('team_user')
                    ->where('league_id',  $this->league_id )
                    ->where('user_id',  $this->user_id )
                    ->first()
                    ->team_id;

    $team = Team::find( $team_id );

    return $team;

  }
```

In my controller

```
foreach( $league->winners as $winner)
      {
        $winner['team'] = $winner->team();
      }
```